# Usage of "other" with "except for" and "apart from"

Tags: word-usage

Should I use **other** in the following sentence with **except for** and **apart from**?

- **Except for/apart from** myself, There are four **(other)** people in my family.

Answer (score 1):

Your options are the following:

You can say, after referring to yourself in conversation that *there are four **other** people in my family*. (Equally, you might have referred to yourself and your brother or sister, meaning that there were more than five in total.)

or

**Apart from me, there are four people in my family.**

To include **other** here is unnecessary although, again, some might do so for emphasis.

**Apart from me** is preferable to *apart from myself* although it's permissible to say *apart from **me** myself* for the sake of emphasis.

**Apart from** is more idiomatic than **except for** in this context although both are correct.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/when-to-use-myself-and-yourself